# Who is msg.sender in a nested delegatecall chain?

Tags: solidity, evm, delegatecall, smart-contract

Who is the **msg.sender** in emitted event by calling **callMe** method on contract **D**?

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

contract A {

    event LogMsgSender(address who);

    function callMe() public {
        emit LogMsgSender(msg.sender);
    }
}

contract B {

    function callMe(address a) public {
        a.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("callMe()")
        );
    }
}

contract C {

    function callMe(address a, address b) public {
         b.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("callMe(address)",a)
        );
    }
}

contract D {

    function callMe(address a, address b, address c) public {
        c.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("callMe(address,address)",a,b)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the original `msg.sender` (the one who calls `callMe` on contract D) because msg.sender context are all the same in D,C,B,A. For example, user having an account `0x1111...` calls `callMe(a,b,c)` on D, the `msg.sender` logged on contract A (address `a`) will be `0x1111...`
Read more about delegate calls on [Solidity Document](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?#delegatecall-callcode-and-libraries)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just asked this question because I could not find the answer untill run the above example.